# how can I add a function in the replacement of preg_replace in php?

Tags: php, function, preg-replace

This seems to work ok:

```
function findImageTags($string) {       
    $pattern = '/<div(.*?)sourcefile="([^"]+)"(.*?)>(.*?)<\/div>/s';
    return preg_replace($pattern, $this->generateImage("$2"), $string);
}

function generateImage($url){
    return $url;
}
```

But when in the generateImage function I try to do something with the argument I can't because the value of the argument is $2 instead of the real value.

So this doesn't work:

```
function generateImage($url){
    $array = explode('.', $url);
    return $array;
}
```

by the way replacing s with e in the pattern doesn't seem to work as I think it's deprecated.

So how can I manipulate the value of the argument in generateImage() ?

Comment: I've just figure out I could do something like this to call an external method using preg_replace_callback. array(get_class($this), 'generateImage')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is probably [preg_replace_callback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) instead of `preg_replace`. Here you can use a function which returns the replacement value.

Answer (score 0):

The way you coded it now, the `$this->generateImage("$2")` code is executed at the moment you call `preg_replace`. It's not passed as a callback, but instead it's executed first, and the output is passed as the callback.

If you want to execute that function, you have to pass the PHP code as a string, and use the `e` modifier (http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php for more info).

```
return preg_replace($pattern, '$this->generateImage("$2")', $string);
```

Or use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) of course.

Comment: isn't the e modifier deprecated?

Comment: It's not deprecated, but: "discouraged, as it can easily introduce security vulnerabilites".

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for with the e, it can't find the pattern apparently (even though it does with the s)